Squished ```\equiv'''
I am looking for a "squished" three-line equality symbol, \equiv, as in the picture below. Is it possible to produce such a symbol without it looking too similar to equality and \equiv? Ideally, it will also be lengthened a bit horizontally.

\Equiv in unicode-math is a four bar symbol which will always be more visually distinct than a three bar variation, so could be an option?

@DavidCarlisle I don’t really want four lines, though, since four lines takes up too much vertical space.

@campa Essentially all I am looking for is the (three) lines that make up \equiv to be closer together. I do not want them to be tilde-like.

Ah, OK, vote retracted. But that is really not clear from your low-resolution photo...

@campa Sorry. Maybe I can't draw well.

Put two \equiv signs with some backup in the middle.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Equiv}{\equiv\joinrel\equiv}

\begin{document}

$a = b$

$a \equiv b$

$a \Equiv b$

\end{document}


The amount of backing up is 3mu. If you want a shorter symbol, try
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Equiv}{\equiv\mathrel{\mkern-9mu}\equiv}

\begin{document}

$a = b$

$a \equiv b$

$a \Equiv b$

\end{document}


Experiment with the amount.

Using scalerel package with the option \hstretch{<horizontal stretch measure>}{\equiv} you can obtain an strectch \equiv.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  A & \hstretch{2}{\equiv} B \\
    & = C\\
    & = D \\
    & \hstretch{1}{\equiv} E \\
    & \hstretch{1.5}{\equiv} F
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


